# How can I create an Instagram sharer link in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, instagram-api

How can I share a post on Instagram with PHP?

My code here:

```
<a class="fb-share" href="https://www.instagram.com/sharer.php?u={{url()->current()}}"><i class="social_facebook"></i> Share</a>
```

I am using Laravel.

Comment: @rafe no, Instagram doesn't want this feature, so they don't have a way to do this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Instagram currently doesn’t allow you to share a photo or video from another website – you can only upload photos/videos directly from your mobile device. Since there isn't any sharing mechanism, there isn't any way for us to include a button that will share your content to Instagram.

You can if you have a business account, but there are restrictions. See *[Content Publishing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing)*.

But, this also isn't a share button.

Comment: Can you please share any official reference link related to same statement, we need that.

Comment: @DeepKakkar see update

Comment: Also -> https://blog.hootsuite.com/how-to-create-social-media-buttons/#:~:text=Instagram%20does%20not%20offer%20Share,liking%20and%20sharing%20web%20content.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I appreciate it if you share the official link from Instagram for this.

Comment: @DeepKakkar there isn't one